# How to redirect a page using Session ID

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-templates, django-views

I am displaying qr code on a page and save the session id regarding qr code to authenticate the user.Once the user scan the qr code, the scanner app send response by using callback URI. I have received the response for specific user now how I can redirect the user using Session ID. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can redirect to page with:

```
window.location.href = "www.yourredirecturlhere.com";
```